# Formatting Highcharts labels with a callback function (Formatter)

Tags: d3.js, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to remove the last 3 numbers and replace it with a string 'k' on one labelled chart axis.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    labels: {
      formatter: function () {
        if (this.value >= 1000) {
          return this.value.slice(0, -3) + 'k'
        } else {
          return this.value
        }
```

Doing it this way gives me an error.

Comment: Hey! Have a look at Intl.FormatNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my mistake, here's how I fixed it:

```
   formatter: function () {
        if (this.value >= 1000) {
          return this.value.toString().slice(0, -3) + 'k';
        } else {
          return this.value
        }
      },
```